# Solving this simple variable coefficient ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck with a slightly more involved variant of the following, quite elementary I suppose, variable coefficient ordinary differential equation:

\begin{equation}
i\frac{d}{dx} p + a(x)p(x) = 0 \,, \qquad p(0) = 1
\end{equation}
where $a \in C^\infty([0,\beta])$ is complex valued (ideally no more conditions are required, what I probably need is that it is non-vanishing).

Of course if $a$ were a non-zero constant then the solution is $p(x) = e^{\,iax}$, but here I am not sure how to proceed. Eventually I'd need to understand the solution in the case where this is a system (so $a \in GL(n\mathbb{C})$ and so on) but for now I should concentrate on understanding the scalar - case.

Any hints as to where to read up on this or basic ideas would be hugely helpful to get started. I appologize in case this is too elementary, my ode - knowledge is unfortunately very sketchy and I hope I can change this going forward. Many thanks!

Comment: There's a common method for solving the scalar case, at least.  The key phrase to search for is "integrating factor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $p$ satisfies the initial value problem
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} p -i a(x)p(x) = 0 \,, \qquad p(0) = 1.
\end{equation}
Then
$$
\left(\exp\left(-i\int_0^x a(t)\,dt\right)p(x)\right)'=
\exp\left(-i\int_0^x a(t)\,dt\right)\big(\frac{d}{dx} p -i a(x)p(x)\big) = 0,
$$
and hence $\exp\left(-i\int_0^x a(t)\,dt\right)p(x)$ is constant, which implies that
$$
\exp\left(-i\int_0^x a(t)\,dt\right)p(x)=\exp\left(-i\int_0^0 a(t)\,dt\right)p(0)=1,
$$
and therefore
$$
p(x)=\exp\left(i\int_0^x a(t)\,dt\right).
$$